# How to get computed style change for an element

Tags: javascript, css, getcomputedstyle

I want to listen for element style changes (in particular in the case of `:hover` and/or `insertRule`). I can calculate the actual style with `getComputedStyle` and clone it into another object and then make diff every `mouseenter`/`mouseleave` (or `MutationObserver`), but it seems like rather low-performance solution for me. Is there any better way to track the element style changes?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you can use a css variable and calc. With calc you can for example subtract `20px` from `100%`

Comment: Don't get your point. What I'm talking about is getComputedStyle API